# send email using different template based on persons name laravel php

Tags: php, database, laravel, email, phpmyadmin

i am working on sending email as batch to list of emails coming from database. however when emails are sent they are not dynamic i.e. are the same for each users can someone tell me what i am doing wrong please thanks.

web.php

```
Route::post('/sendmail', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, 
\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer) {
$x = 1;
while($x <= 10) {
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=website4.0;host=localhost", "root", "");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = ("SELECT name, email FROM students WHERE studentID=$x");   
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$values = $statement->fetchAll();


$mailer
->to($values)

->send(new \App\Mail\Mymail($request->input('title')));
   $x++;
}
return redirect()->back();
})-> name('sendmail');


<?php
```

This is the template so for id=1 it needs to get the name of id 1 and post that in the email atm it is only sending id ones template to all emails it needs to send individual templates to the users with their specific names.

mymail.php

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=website4.0;host=localhost", "root", "");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = ("SELECT title, date, address, intro, mainbody, paragraph, footer 
FROM template");

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$values = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($values as $row){
 $row["title"];
 $row["date"];
 $row['address'];
 $row["intro"];
 $row["mainbody"];
 $row["paragraph"];
 $row["footer"];

 }



echo  '<h1>'.$row["title"]. '</h1>';
echo '<p>' .$row["date"]. '</p>'; 
echo  $row["address"]; 


$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=website4.0;host=localhost", "root", "");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = ("SELECT name FROM students where studentID=1");

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$values = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($values as $row){

 $row["name"];

 echo $row["name"]; 
}
```

Comment: Your code here doesn't make use of many Laravel features, is there a reason you're using `PDO` directly instead of using Eloquent? If you're open to using native Laravel features -- like Eloquent -- then it'll be easier to provide an answer.

Comment: more experience with pdo

Comment: This seems painfully obvious, but you have studentID=1 hardcoded where you retrieve the name, instead of using a variable passed to the mymail.php script. I'm not too familiar with Laravel, just here from the php tag... let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: i see, what variable should i replace this with sorry bit of a novice

Comment: i have tried looping the id however instead of displaying the name of specific id it displays all names